# First difference estimator (Panel Data) manually on R

Tags: r, dplyr, panel-data, plm

I am trying to estimate the first difference estimator by creating a column with the difference between the value and the first lag. I don't know why, but the result is different from the function from the package plm. What is my mistake?

```
library(plm)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
cities <- rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), each=4)
time <- rep(c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'), 5)
panel <- data.frame(City=cities, Month=time)
panel$X <- rnorm(20,2,1)
panel$Y <- 5+2*panel$X+rnorm(20)

#Using the package
summary(plm(Y~X, model='fd',data=panel,index = c('City', 'Month')))
#Estimate=1.67741

#Manually
panel$diff_lag_Y <- ave(panel$Y, panel$City, FUN = function(x) x- dplyr::lag(x))
panel$diff_lag_X<- ave(panel$X, panel$City, FUN =  function(x) x- dplyr::lag(x))

summary(lm(panel$diff_lag_Y~panel$diff_lag_X, data=panel))
#Estimate=1.8372
```

Comment: I just realize that if I replace the current vector by time<- rep(c('1', '2', '3', '4'), 5) it works perfectly. So, by some reason the months names are not understood in the right order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The months need to be assigned as a factor vector, so the order is clear.

```
library(plm)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
cities <- rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), each=4)
time <- rep(factor(c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'), levels =c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr') ), 5)
panel <- data.frame(City=cities, Month=time)
panel$X <- rnorm(20,2,1)
panel$Y <- 5+2*panel$X+rnorm(20)

#Using the package
summary(plm(Y~X, model='fd',data=panel,index = c('City', 'Month')))
#Estimate=1.8372

#Manually
panel$diff_lag_Y <- ave(panel$Y, panel$City, FUN = function(x) x- dplyr::lag(x))
panel$diff_lag_X<- ave(panel$X, panel$City, FUN =  function(x) x- dplyr::lag(x))

summary(lm(panel$diff_lag_Y~panel$diff_lag_X, data=panel))
#Estimate=1.8372
```